# Accented characters stopped working on French Canadian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've been using the French (Canada) keyboard for a while now but recently, the key combinations I've been using to write accented characters have stopped working.

Usually, when writing accented characters, I'd press an accent key followed by a letter key to get the character. For example:

<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> = `è`

<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> = `î`

<kbd>¸</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> = `ç`

However, for a couple of days now, the combinations don't work. Instead of the expected output, I get:

<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> = `` `e ``

<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> = `^i`

<kbd>¸</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> = `¸c`

To fix the problem, I tried to restore the keyboard parameters to default but nothing changed. I also tried to use the compose key but no success.

compose +<kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> = `e`

compose +<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> = `i`

compose +<kbd>¸</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> = `c`

Is there a way to restore this function to the keyboard? Did a config file get changed, causing this behavior?

Thanks!

**Info:** 
OS : Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit 
Laptop : Asus K56CM

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday: neither *dead keys* nor *compose key* input methods were working on GTK based applications like `gedit`. 
Then I found this answer: [Dead keys suddenly stopped working in GTK applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415527/dead-keys-suddenly-stopped-working-in-gtk-applications) which suggested doing `apt-get install ibus`. That solved the problem for me!