# Dead keys suddenly stopped working in GTK applications

Tags: keyboard, gtk, dead-keys

I use several keyboards layouts on a regular basis. Two of which make use of dead keys for French language.

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT=us,fr,fr
XKBVARIANT=dvp,bepo,latin9
BACKSPACE=guess
```

This morning, after a `sudo apt-get upgrade` on Debian 9 (stretch), which may or may not be involved in the problem, dead keys stopped working as dead keys (*i.e.* hitting `^` then `e` produces `^e` instead of `ê`), which makes typing french quite difficult.

The new behaviour is persistent after reboot and affects several applications:

- firefox
- thunderbird
- gnome-terminal
- gedit
- nautilus

But **not** VLC or xterm.. what should I conclude?
How do I get my dead keys working again in all applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, on Debian Stretch, and I am using bépo too.

I solved it by using IBUS (yet I guess FCITX and some others can manage it too).

To me, dead keys worked fine in TTY. So I guess the problem «only» happen in software getting keyboard configuration from GUI (X?).

To install Ibus: 
sudo apt-get install ibus

Ibus comes with a GUI configuration tool, and bépo is available.
Setting Ibus to start automatically with the session can help.

Comment: Well, it finally works after a reboot I think :D (unless the bug's gone alone XD) Thank you again :)