# How to get accented characters instead of quotes?

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-layout, input-method

I'm using Gnome desktop environment on Debian 9.5, my laptop is Acer Aspire V5 series.

I usually cycle through three keyboard languages during the day: English, Italian and Spanish. The first two layouts work perfectly, but just today 
I realize that the Spanish layout is giving me quotation marks when it should give me accented characters. For instance:

<kbd>'</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>, should produce " *é* ", but it is giving me " *´e* " instead.

I've been using this version of Debian and Gnome Desktop since a year ago, and I never had this problem before. This week I had an `apt upgrade` of the system, so I suspect that action unleashed the problem. I wonder if it is a bug of the latest updated software or maybe that the firmware of my keyboard needs to be updated.

Please, if there is anyone out there having the same problem I would like some hints on how can it be fixed.

#### EDIT 1

This fellow had the same problem two years ago, but unfortunately his question was never answered: [Accented characters stopped working on French Canadian keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314044/accented-characters-stoped-working-on-french-cannadian-keyboard).

Comment: [This thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/keyboard-entry-of-accented-characters-946902/) suggests two things: 1) run the script in the thread and see what compose options you have 2) Open System Menu --> Preferences --> Keyboard Layout --> Layouts tab --> Select your layout --> Options --> Compose key. [This debian manual page](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html) suggests `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` or `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`,  and make sure the settings are reasonable.

Comment: @roaima, So this is being reopened, so that it can be closed as a dupe?  Shouldn't that be a mod flag?

Comment: @roaima - I reopened this.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I reopened this.

Comment: If you'd like you can move your solution from the Q to an A'er and then mark yours as accepted. I cleaned up the edits so it should be just a copy/paste job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Google searching I found that my old method for input accented characters is known as *dead keys*, there are other methods like *compose key*;
as it is suggested in this: [[SOLVED] keyboard entry of "accented" characters](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/keyboard-entry-of-accented-characters-946902/) - (thank you Nick ODell).

After trying every possible solution I discovered that the input methods were not working on `gedit`, `terminal` and `evolution`, but they did in `Libre Office`. So I went to tackle the problem on GTK by Google searching again and I found this: [Dead keys suddenly stopped working in GTK applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415527/dead-keys-suddenly-stopped-working-in-gtk-applications).

I gave a try to `apt-get install ibus` and that solved the problem.